# Angular CLI project load component as base URL

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I have a Angular CLI project that i built with multiple components and uploaded via FileZilla to my school domain. I want it so that on load of the application it redirects to the HomeComponent instead of AppComponent. What can i do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your router set the default route to your home component URL.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '',
    redirectTo: '/home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
];
```